# How to replace a specific character using Visio find and replace

Tags: find-and-replace, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2016

Using Visio 2016.  I want to do a page-scoped find and replace to renumber a bunch of part labels from, e.g., 301, 302, 303, ... to 401, 402, 403, ...

The Visio find and replace includes a wildcard for the find function:

[image: Screenshot of Visio find and replace dialog.]

but it does not function as an anchor or placeholder for the replaced string, instead replacing, e.g., 303 with 4.  Is this possible with the find and replace dialog?  Or with a VBA macro?

Answer (score 2):

You might try opening the *Visio* [.vsdx](https://docs.fileformat.com/visio/vsdx/) file in a text editor, such as [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), which *does* have Regex search & replace.

- Make a **copy** of the *Visio* document and perform these operations on the *copy*, lest something go wrong.
- "[T]he *Visio* 2013 file format uses... an archive such as ZIP, [which] can be extracted using any standard extraction utility," such as [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/). Using *7-Zip*, if its context-menu has been enabled, in Explorer, right-click the file to open it -- no need to change filename.
- Extract all files in the *Visio* document, leaving the zip tool open.
- Find the file (in XML format) containing the text strings, e.g. "301".
- Edit the file, e.g., replacing "3*nn*" with '4*nn*".
- Save the file.
- Restore the file to the archive *replacing the original* (e.g., in *7-Zip*, drag and drop the file into the archive).
- Test the copy to make sure it still works in *Visio*.